# Using "Bundle Update" in Rails produced bazillion errors on test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler, gemfile

I'm trudging through this deeply error-prone tutorial on Ruby on Rails located here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.

I've been working through a section about testing using rspec.  Now, the instructions that this tutorial provided created a whole host of errors (deprecations, array issues, etc.) that filled up my page.  After rummaging the internet for several hours, I decided to follow several suggestions to update all my gems.

Having updated my gems and attempted to perform this very basic test (the default test really), I got this whole pile of error that I couldn't begin to understand.  All I can say is "please help".

Thank you.

```
> bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
←[31mF←[0m

Failures:

  1) StaticPages GET /static_pages works! (now write some real specs)
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mget static_pages_path←[0m
     ←[31mNameError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined local variable or method `static_pages_path' for #<RSpec::
Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x5168040>←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top
(required)>'←[0m

Finished in 0.19901 seconds
←[31m1 example, 1 failure←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:5←[0m ←[36m# StaticPages GET /st
atic_pages works! (now write some real specs)←[0m
```

Comment: can you added your actual test code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded all your gems to the latest, then one issue you probably have is your newer capybara gem no longer looks for your tests in **'spec/requests'**. That test needs to be in **'spec/features'** now. If there is no **'spec/features'** just create it.

Also, capybara will need this line in your **'spec/spec_helper.rb'** if it isn't already:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```